# Laravel: How update a json that has dynamic key using laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a JSON that is stored in the MySQL database, using this format

```
{
    "doctor_id": "1",
    "day_id": "1",
    "time_slots": {
    "slot1": {
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "09:30",
        "selected": false
    },
    "slot2": {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end": "10:30",
        "selected": false
    }
}
```

I want to query the database using eloquent and update the

> selected: false

to

> selected: true

NOTE: the slot1 and slot2 are dynamic, it's coming from the user

what I want to do is something like

```
$appointment::where('doctor_id', 1)
    ->where('day_id', 1)
    ->whereJsonContains('time_slots->*->start', 09:00)
    ->whereJsonContains('time_slots->*->end', 09:30)
    ->update(['time_slots->*->selected' => true]);
```

The `*` will be a placeholder

Comment: I think you need to change your design to make `time_slots` an array and instead of having what the user passes as the key you can have it as an extra field in each array entry (e.g. `time_slots: [ { start: ..., end: ..., identifier: slot1 } ]`)

Comment: Please @apokryfos can you explain this more, I'm still confused  and don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s5YMtbJ6r1neSaDMXt7RTW/0)

Comment: Thanks, @apokryfos I was able to change the design of the JSON and it worked.
I am now faced with the challenge of how to update the JSON using the Update() method